# Bootstrap Scrollspy - How to get a dropdown list to scrollspy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure how to explain this with only words - so lets start with an image showing what I would like to accomplish with code:

[image]

So basically, what I want to accomplish:

1. All sections (anchors) of the page should be in the drop down.
2. The drop down should work as a menu - clicking an item should take (scroll) you to the specific section.
3. When scrolling through the page, the drop down should view/indicate what section you are currently viewing.

My knowledge/understanding about js is very limited, so I might be missing the obvious when reading the bootstrap documentation. But whatever I try, it seems I can't get the drop down to indicate what section is currently in the browsers view point.

Not even the official example is doing what I want to accomplish, as you can see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-examples). It only indicates that SOME item in the "Dropdown" is viewed, not the specific item that is actually being viewed.

If I'm not able to accomplish this with bootstrap, is there any other ways?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, no answers. Very surprisingly for being Stackoverflow, how should I interpret this? Is it impossible? ;-)

Comment: Still no feedback on this topic? Can someone at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Guys, need some feedback on how to create this feature. Maybe it isn't possible to tweak boostrap to do this? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a bit late but I had this problem and just searched this on Google and found an answer :)

`Scrollspy` has a fantastic event:

```
$('#myScrollspy').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
 // do something… 
})
```

On the 'do something' area, you can catch the element that just received the 'active' class, get its identifier, and update your dropdown :)